# ADO.NET Data Services .NET client caching

Tags: caching, wcf-data-services, astoria

On my service, I've added the following method:

```
    protected override void OnStartProcessingRequest(ProcessRequestArgs args)
    {
        base.OnStartProcessingRequest(args);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
    }
```

My client is the regular generated .net client. Nothing appears to be cached. It's going to the server on every request. What needs to be done to enable caching?
Thanks,
-jaa

Comment: Does the client even support caching?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do HTTP caching however ADO.NET Data Services is being smarter and making sure client driven caching like this does cause old data to come through.

If you want to due client driven caching you need to set the [ETag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541486(PROT.10).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Any real ETag examples?

So far only rubbish references to not real examples